# Update J2ObjC library in Xcode10

Tags: ios, xcode10, j2objc

I'm currently working on an app in Xcode10 which references the J2ObjC library.

When trying to build the app i get the following errors. See line 486-490 in image below. [image]

I currently have j2objc version  0.9.8.2.1, but would like to update this to a new version as i believe the update would fix the issue. How can I update the library to a newer version?

I'm new to ios , so not sure exactly where to get instructions. I checked the [official website](https://cocoapods.org/pods/J2ObjC) but with no luck.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The CocoaPods site is not the official website: the j2objc team doesn't support CocoaPods (our team is too small), so community members contributed it independently.

What is supported is using Xcode frameworks. In the [latest j2objc release](https://github.com/google/j2objc/releases/latest), the distribution bundle contains a j2objc/frameworks directory; [here is the doc](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/guides/xcode-build-rules#update_the_build_settings) on updating Xcode to reference this directory.

Comment: Thanks Tball for the effort...unfortunately i've not been able to resolved the issue, due to lack of technical ios knowledge & help so this has been parked for now.

Comment: After seeing the code generate by the j2obc tool i think i'll stick to C# for now and we'll get a dedicated ios dev to look at this.